# How to solve the eroor : ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table '#sql-2b45_9606' is full in mysql

Tags: mysql

I got the error ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table '#sql-2b45_9606' is full while I creating the index like `mysql> CREATE INDEX fc_customerjobs_reserved04  ON customerjobs (reserved04(45));` . Can anyone have this experience and know the solution for solving that issue. 
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index are created in a temp table which has a limited size, so There may b many indexes in that schema.
Note:: indexes for varchar occupy more space than that of numbers.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of temp table. Is it show means can you please tell me where I need to update for the purpose of increasing space.

Comment: its possible by an alter statement in oracle but not in Mysql :-(
U check what are the indexes associated on that table...

Answer (score 0):

You might be running out of space either in the partition where the mysql tables are stored (usually /var/lib/mysql) or in where the temporary tables are stored (usually /tmp).

You may want to:
- monitor your free space during the index creation.
- point the tmpdir MySQL variable to a different location.  This requires a server restart.